# Delta max for each element in collection

Tags: algorithm, sorting, max, time-complexity

Given an unsorted collection of integers, is it possible to find delta max for each element in a single iteration?

Thus, for [0,7,6,4] the result is [7,0,1,3]

If one is allowed to compute max while the collection is being populated the answer is yes, but is there another solution?

This was an internship interview question.

Comment: What is "delta max"?

Comment: @kraskevich: Looks and sounds like the difference between the max and that element. In which case the question is kind of trivial; just make two passes...

Comment: the difference between an element and the largest element in the collection

Comment: O(2n) is still O(n). Simply loop through the array twice.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I had forgotten that, I will edit the question.

Comment: You could also argue that if you have the max then you also have found delta max for each element, you just need a subtraction (but to construct the delta max array you need 2 iterations)